Would it make more sense to mermaid species to split based on ocean depth or temperature?
I am working on the evolution of mermaids into various species. I've considered having them evolve for depth, ie surface/coastal mermaids and deep/far out mermaids. I've also considered having them evolve for temperature, ie tropical/temperate/arctic.
My mermaids are aquatic mammals, similar to dolphins. They have lungs and are insulated by blubber.
Which of these would make more sense? Which of them provides stronger environmental pressure?

You mean "races" or "breeds," not "species." Cats and dogs are two species. Bulldogs and Hound dogs are two breeds of the species dog. Generally, "races" is used for humans so it would make sense to use with merfolk. As for your question, what do you see in humanity? For us, one reason for races is obviously isolation. So, how would temperature and/or depth create isolation?

I'm not talking about races or breeds, I'm talking about species. Not like Ethiopians and Norwegians, like blue whales and humpback whales, which have different scientific designations.

Species cannot interbreed (with incredibly rare exceptions, e.g., male donkey + female horse = mule). Species are the result of serious isolation or evolutionary time. From that perspective, depth will do it (if there's enough), temperature won't. Salt water vs fresh water would also do it.

Sorry perhaps I should clarify better. I mean that they are separate species NOW but they originated as a single species, at some point in the past they could interbreed, and if they'd done so too much they'd never become separate species.

Hmmm... this suggests that you need to [edit] your question to specify exactly how much difference you want between each group and completely avoid using scientific terms. Those differences are important to understand to help you decide how to isolate your groups.

Presumably they split to take advantage of food-sources or safety from predation in these different environments - can you edit to give us details of the problem you're facing, as it's not at all clear what the issue is.

I'm trying to determine whether I'd have "tropical, temperate, and arctic" mermaid species or "shallow and deep" mermaid species.

shallow and deep will be your biggest diffrent, deep diving for an air breathing species requires a lot of adaptations esspecally for a small species.

What do seals do? They breathe air and hold their breath when diving, like human free divers. They have horizontal flukes to their tail like mermaids. Some of them are more massive than humans, and some are lighter. The ones in the middle are not that far from the mermaids you describe. So, let's start with seals...
Most seals live in the cooler waters. They are separated into southern and northern hemisphere populations, some freshwater sites (the Baikal seal), and a few islands in warmer climates, such as the Hawaiian Monk seal. There were probably more island populations such as the Caribbean Monk Seal that have gone extinct due to hunting.
Seals are air breathing. The more massive ones can go deep. Southern Elephant seals can dive to 2000m and stay down for 2 hours. These can weigh up to 4 tons. If you are looking for something of similar body mass to a human, try the Harbour seal. This has a typical body mass of 87 Kg. They can dive to 500m and stay under for 20 minutes, but most dives are less than 4 minutes, and do not go deeper than 20m.
All seals in an area share the surface, and all live close to the shore. They do not dive deep when they do not have to, so they are unlikely segregate by diving depth. It may be the more massive, deep diving species will not share a beach with smaller seals, but this is because they are bigger, not because they dive deep.
If we model mermaids on harbour seals and the like, there will be two belts of populated water in the colder waters of either hemisphere. There can be isolated populations around Pacific island chains, and freshwater seals in large lakes.

Modern cetaceans on Earth are speciated mainly on the basis of geography (ten thousand miles is a long way to swim) and temperature, but that almost exclusively in dolphins and a few smaller species of whales.  Narwhals are found only in northern cold waters -- but most of the larger whales are globally distributed.  Even orcas (which are actually dolphins) range from arctic/antarctic to at least subtropical waters and cross the equator from time to time.
Generally, however, it'll be the larger species that handle temperature variation better.  Sperm whales dive deep, potentially ranging from water temperatures of 25 C at the tropical surface to as low as -2 C during a deep dive (yes, sea water under great pressure is still liquid at this "sub-freezing" temperature).  Baleen whales seldom dive as deep as the toothed whales, and no others as deep as sperm whales.
So, speciation of your oceanic mammal mermaids might be all down to their progenitor being small enough not to tolerate wide temperature ranges, and having a major continent (chain) like the Americas between their original habitats.

Differences in mermaid species could develop for different salinity levels in the water. Some seas have higher salinity levels than other and maybe travelling individuals will be able to feel the difference. This also allows for mermaids which prefer to live in rivers and lakes.
Variety in scales and breathing methods might also emerge, which would further separate these races from one another.
